# Error as :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id 5004B000000qt8r,5004B000000qt8w must be 15 characters

Tags: custom-button, case-object

Can any help me out with this Error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id 5004B000000qt8r,5004B000000qt8w must be 15 characters

I have a custom button created as "Mass Close" button using javascript.

```
var ids= {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; 
if(ids.length < 1 ) 
alert('Please select at least one row.'); 
else 
window.open('/apex/MassCloseCasesPage?ids='+ids.join(','));
```

Code :

```
public with sharing class MassCloseCasesController { 

      public Case objCase {get;set;} 
      private List<Case> lstCase{get;set;} 
      public MassCloseCasesController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController) 
                            { 
                               objCase = new Case(); 
                               lstCase = new List<Case>(); 
                               lstCase = (List<Case>) standardController.getSelected();


     } 
     public PageReference save() 
                           { 
                              for(Case objCaseRecord: lstCase) 
                            { 
                              objCaseRecord.Status = objCase.Status; 
                              objCaseRecord.Reason_For_Resolution__c = objCase.Reason_For_Resolution__c; 
                              objCaseRecord.Comment__c = objCase.Comment__c; 
                              objCaseRecord.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c = objCase.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c; 
                            } 
                              update lstCase; 
                              return new pagereference('/500'); 

                           } 
     public PageReference cancel() 
                            { 
                              return new pagereference('/500'); 
                          } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public with sharing class MassCaseClose {

      public Case objCase {get;set;} 
      private List<Case> lstCase; 
      public MassCaseClose() 
      { 
           objCase = new Case(); 
           lstCase = new List<Case>(); 
           String strRecordIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
            set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
            for(String strid : strRecordIds.split(','))
            {
                setCaseIds.add(id.valueof(strid.trim()));
            }
            lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN: setCaseIds];
     } 
     public PageReference save() 
   { 
      for(Case objCaseRecord: lstCase) 
    { 
      objCaseRecord.Status = objCase.Status; 
      objCaseRecord.Reason_For_Resolution__c = objCase.Reason_For_Resolution__c; 
      objCaseRecord.Comment__c = objCase.Comment__c; 
      objCaseRecord.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c = objCase.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c; 
    } 
      update lstCase; 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 

   } 
     public PageReference cancel() 
    { 
      return new pagereference('/500'); 
  } 

}
```

Vf page

```
<apex:page controller="MassCaseClose" sidebar="false" > 
  <apex:form > 
    <apex:SectionHeader title="Close Cases"/> 
      <apex:pageBlock > 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Both"> 
          <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/> 
          <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
           <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Case Information" > 
             <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Status}"/> 
             <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Reason_For_Resolution__c}" label="Reason For Resolution"/> 
             <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Comment__c}" label="Internal Comments"/> 
             <apex:inputField value="{!objCase.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c}" label="Do Not Send Email Case Closure"/> 
          </apex:pageBlockSection> 
       </apex:pageBlock> 
   </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

now try this should work

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.First i created in that way..Since we would like have the standard functionality of Close button .when user clicks on the  close button  without selecting any cases for closer at that time gives an alert as "please select at least one row".so to get this alert i need to use javascript or do we have any alternative way.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: hey @nikkey now check my comment. let me know if you getting any issue

Comment: i get an error as Error: Unknown constructor 'MassCloseCasesController.MassCloseCasesController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Comment: @nikkey dont use standard controller here.. check my code. use only controller. I have tested this in my org it is working as you expected

Comment: how many records you have selected?

Comment: @RatanPaul I would vote up your answer if it started with some text outlining what the problem is and your approach to fixing it. Reposting all the code with a few lines fixed might be good for the person asking the question but makes it hard for others to see the change.